# Huge performance differences between i5 i7 SSD/non SSD...which makes more of a difference?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, cpu

I have 2 pcs both running Windows 8.1 and each with 8b of ram.

The differences are one has a solid state drive the other one is 7200rpm and also an i7 vs i5

Running the same application one query takes 300 ms on the SSD and i7 machine while on the i5 and regular hard drive takes 1.8 seconds

Is the difference in performance related to processor or SSD?

This is a MySQL 5 database application doing multiple select statements using LIKE %%

Comment: database is primary a memory and I/O limited.

Comment: So  based on that ssd drive might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSD is providing most of the performance benefit, hands down.

As Ramhound mentioned, database performance is generally bound to memory and I/O performance. An SSD provides a quantum leap in performance benefit compared to a HDD in regards to random accesses (which is most likely your usage pattern).

i5 vs. i7 wouldn't provide a performance benefit of several times the original like you're seeing.